# X86 Microsoft assembly language arithmetic calculations

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I want to solve an equation `-2[-3(x-2y)+ 2y/2]` and display the answer on the command-line interface, given a user inputs the values of both X and Y. Is there a way of performing operations between an 8-bit register and a 16-bit register?

For example MOV AX,AL. I am getting a problem as the registers keep growing every time after a `MUL` instruction. I have tried to do `(X-2y)` and now having problems to multiply `-3` with the result!

Here is my code:

```
.model small

    .stack 100h

    .data 

        open db 'Please enter value between 0 - 9 below:',13,10,'$'
        req1 db 'Enter the value for X:',13,10,'$'
        req2 db 'Enter the value for Y:',13,10,'$'
        ans1 db 'After Multiplying Y by 2, we get: $' 
        ans2 db 'After Subtracting the result from X, we get: $' 
        ans3 db 'After multiplying the result by -3, we get: $'
        ans db 'After Adding the fifth number from the result, we get: $'

    var1 dw ?

    var2 db ?

    var3 db ?

    var4 db ?

    var5 db ?

    ans11 dw ?

    ans22 dw ? 

    ans33 dd ?


    .code

    main proc

        mov ax,@data
        mov ds,ax

        mov dx,OFFSET open  ;copies the starting address into the dx register.
        mov ah,9h     ;calling DOS sub program for displaying a character.
        int 21h       ;returning controlto the operating system.
        mov dx,OFFSET req1
        mov ah,9h
        int 21h

        mov ah,1h
        int 21h
        sub ah,'0'
        mov var1,ax

        mov dl,13d
        mov ah,2h
        int 21h

        mov dl,10d
        mov ah,2h
        int 21h

        mov dx,OFFSET req2  ;loading the start address of the variable req2 into the DX register.
        mov ah,9h  ;dos sub program for displaying a string.
        int 21h    ;dos interrupt to display the string on the screen

        mov ah,1h  ;prompts some one to enter a character from the keyboard.
        int 21h     ; captures a character from the keyboard and stores it in the AL register.
        sub al,'0'  ;stripping off the ASCII from AL to get the Actual Integer Value.
        mov var2,al ; storing the integer value in the variable var2.

        mov dl,13d
        mov ah,2h
        int 21h

        mov dl,10d
        mov ah,2h
        int 21h


        ;**************
        mov dx,OFFSET ans1
        mov ah,9h
        int 21h

        mov ax,0
        mov bx,0
        mov al,var2
        mov bl,2
        mul bx
        mov ans11,ax
        aam
        add ah,30h
        add al,30h

        mov cx,ax
        mov dl,ch
        mov ah,2h
        int 21h

        mov dl,cl
        mov ah,2h
        int 21h

        mov dl,13d
        mov ah,2h
        int 21h

        mov dl,10d
        mov ah,2h
        int 21h     
        ;*************** 
        mov dx,offset ans2 
        mov ah,9h
        int 21h

        mov ax,0
        mov cx,0
        mov dx,var1
        mov cx,ans11
        sub dx,cx

        mov ans22,dx
        mov ax,dx
        aaa
        add ah,30h
        add al,30h

        mov bx,ax
        mov dl,bh
        mov ah,2h
        int 21h

        mov dl,bl
        mov ah,2h
        int 21h

        mov dl,13d
        mov ah,2h
        int 21h

        mov dl,10d
        mov ah,2h
        int 21h  

        ;****************** 

         mov dx,offset ans3
         mov ah,9h
         int 21h

        mov ax,0
        mov bx,0
        mov ax,ans22
        mov bx,-3
        imul bx
        mov ans11,edx:eax
        aam
        add ah,30h
        add al,30h

        mov ecx,edx
        mov ebx,ecx
        mov ah,2h
        int 21h

        mov edx,eax
        mov ah,2h
        int 21h

        mov dl,13d
        mov ah,2h
        int 21h

        mov dl,10d
        mov ah,2h
        int 21h   

        mov ax,4c00H
        int 21h

        ;******************

        main endp
    end main
```

Comment: I don't do assembly, but I can tell you my thoughts... What would you do in C? You don't use larger variables after each multiplication. `int a = 1, b = 2, c = a * b`, `c` is an integer. In assembly you should do the same: discard the "high" register (better check it to be 0) and use only the "low" register. Note that `MUL` is unsigned.

Comment: Define first the valid ranges for those values, if they are 8, 16 or 32 bit. And define what happens if overflown. Truncation to defined range is common (fastest and simplest) solution, so then you can tell that user can enter only -32768..+32767 values for X/Y, and large values like +32767 will be still truncated back to 16 bits (ie. 32767*2 = 32766). About `mov ax,al` ... `al` *is* `ax`, the low 8 bit part of it (just like `ah` is high 8 bit part of `ax`). So `mov ah,0` makes `ax == al` with unsigned logic. But there's dedicated instruction `movzx ax,al` for that, `movsx ax,al` for signed.

Comment: Thanks buddy for the feedback. I'm only new to assembly language programing but let me give a shot to your idea. It must be a nice one. I'm only wondering if it is applicable to all emulators! Could you suggest a good emulator or compiler i can use on a windows platform?